# Regex with (1 to 3 chars at start and later 11 to 13 digits) or (11 to 14 digits) ? char can be lowercase or uppercase

Tags: regex

I am trying to find out regular expression which will detect Reference Number from a string, Ref. No. can be in below format,

[dddddddddddddd] or [a-Z][ddddddddddd] , Ref No can be (1 to 3 chars at start and later 11 to 13 digits) or (11 to 14 digits)

I have tried regex /^[A-Z]{1,3}|[0-9]{11,14}$/ But it is not returning Ref. No. e.g. D1234567891, Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried regex /^[A-Z]{1,3}|[0-9]{11,14}$/ But it is not returning Ref. No. e.g. D1234567891, Any guidance is appeciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample text that should be matched, sample text that should **not** be matched (just as important), and the effort you've made. Don't bury that information in comments where it can't be seen - [edit] your question and add it there. (In addition to the [edit] links I've provided, you can always find an edit link in any of your questions or answers in the lower left  corner (in the case of a question, it's right below the tags you added)).

Answer (score 0):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either 1 to 3 chars at start and later 11 to 13 digits or 11 to 14 digits.

`^(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{11,13}|[0-9]{11,14})$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qzDcMD/1)

**Details**

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{11,13}` Match a lower or uppercase character 1 - 3 times followed by a digit 11 - 13 times
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]{11,14}` Match a digit 11 - 14 times
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line